# App Action Works on App Actions Test Tool But not On Google Assistant

Tags: android, google-assistant, app-actions

I have cloned the project from https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-common-biis-kotlin. I made the package name of this project the same as my draft project in Play Console which has a temporary app name 'com.acesoft.actions (unreviewed)'.  I can trigger the app actions with App Action Test Tool (AATT). If I set the Invocation Name to "test app" with AATT, it would work on my physical test device if I say "Open active tasks in test app". However, Google Assistant would not open the app when I say "Open active tasks in todo". Todo is the display name for the app. According to the documentation, the default invocation name is the display name of the app. The command "Open active tasks in todo" would result in a search in the web. What did I do wrong? How do I invoke the app actions without AATT?

I have also tried typing the following in Google Assistant:

"open active tasks in todo"

"open active tasks in actions" ("actions" is the last part of the temporary name)

All these commands would result in web searches instead of opening the app!
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app is not published on the Play store, it definitely will not work.  Google Assistant only formally recognizes apps that have been uploaded and have passed review.  It works in the test tool because that tool establishes a temporary "preview" of how things will work if it were fully published.

Still, in some cases, Google Assistant is unable to match the name of the app as spoken to the name of the app as installed on the device.  This situation is not possible to resolve on your own.  What you will need to do is contact Google Assistant support and explain what you are trying to do.  They might be able to make a change manually to the backend to enable this.

You can see someone else having a similar problem in [this public bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194922659).  However, **please do not file a new bug, and do not fill out the form unless your app is uploaded to Play**.  If your app is uploaded to Play, follow the instructions given in the last comment on that issue:

> If your app is shipping on the Play store, then you can get support for this using this [support form](https://support.google.com/actions-console/contact/support) - you should choose "App Actions review" for now, and point out that you would like a manual mapping for your app. Don't worry about the actions console project ID - that is for another project.

Comment: Thanks Doug for your reply. You said "Google Assistant only formally recognizes apps that have been uploaded and have passed review." My test app is in "internal testing" and unreviewed. That explains why it does not work with Google Assistant. What if I submit the app to "Closed Testing" or "Open Testing". Will that be considered "reviewed"?

Comment: No, it has to be published so that anyone can download and use it. That will cause a review of your actions to happen.

Comment: That means I can only test my app with Google Assistant after I publish it to the public. I understand that I can use AATT to perform some tests, but I'll have no idea how my app and Google Assistant will behave. I'll have no idea if the default invocation name would work as I have not seen it working yet. Does it make sense that Google allows such an app to be available publicly in the Play Store?

Comment: The only thing you will really not be able to verify is the invocation name.  As I said in my answer, you will have to contact the support team to resolve that, if you do end up finding a problem there.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was enough to put my app into "internal testing" in the Play Console and then install the app on device through the test link that is provided by the Play Console. I could use Google Assistant and use the app name for invocation.